# Android. Supporting 10 - 18 inch screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm sorry, if there is already a question like mine and for my English.

I have received a task where i need support tablets with screens from 10 to 18 inch.

All tutorials, "stackoverflow", "developer.android" and so on, are explain me how to support 10'inch tablets or smaller, xlarge, sw720dp, but what's about bigger sizes.

I have developed layout for resolution 1600, but then i chose device with another dpi, and for "mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, tv, dpi, 280dpi" it's also different. And for every resolution "1080, 768, 800, 600, 1536, 1440, 2048."

I don't think i need to create a lot of layout folders (or values with dimens) for every resolution and dpi, like "layout-land-sw1600dp-mdpi" or (value-w1600dp-mdpi).

Through "weight" it's bad practice how i understood. So i set fixed values.
I have many TextViews with different sp, icons(svg) sizes, margins, paddings. I can't use only match_parent and wrap_content. But if i'm not, there are a lot of values.

And my question, how do it right, and can you help me, please.

PS. How i already said I used internet sources but can't found what i need. Maybe i not very good at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got answer from my mentor. 
I do not know, is it right answer, but it helped me.

I had to use only 3 folders:

- values-sw720dp
- values-sw1080dp
- values-sw1280dp

It worked perfectly, unlike the decisions that i found early.

Answer (score 0):

> All tutorials, "stackoverflow", "developer.android" and so on, are explain me how to support 10'inch tablets or smaller, xlarge, sw720dp, but what's about bigger sizes.

Physical size does not matter at all. I'd suggest you to read these tutorials once more time as you definitely missed what they say. Your starting point should be [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) from official documentation site.

> I don't think i need to create a lot of layout folders (or values with dimens) for every resolution and dpi, like "layout-land-sw1600dp-mdpi" or (value-w1600dp-mdpi)

Unless you need it really (which is in 99% not the case) you should be just fine with "phone", "tablet" and (maybe) "tv". Most layout will scale so what you need to care is to properly handle these groups really and it should be rather sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Despite it not helped me, anyway it's much better then just put minus to my question.

Comment: it seems you prefer to "make things work" instead of "understand how things work"